# modify the text of conditions of use in liferay

Tags: liferay

I work  with  liferay 5.2

I want to change the text which appears after the first login

this text contains the conditions of use

but I didin't find this text in liferay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check \portal-web\docroot\html\portal\terms_of_use.jsp .

There are two ways terms of use appear in liferay.

1. You can set below portal properties in portal-ext.properties to make your web content to visible as term of use content.

   Specify the group id and the article id of the Journal article that will
    be displayed as the terms of use. The default text will be used if no
    Journal article is specified.

   terms.of.use.journal.article.group.id=

   terms.of.use.journal.article.id=
2. If you want to just modify some of part of term of use content which Liferay provides then you can override "terms_of_use.jsp" in hook and provide changes in content.

Comment: If this answer helped you to resolve your issue, then you can mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: @PankajkumarKathiriya i want 'term of use' page on popup instead of LR page, how can i make it work